# Can anyone recommend a pipeline dependency ("make") tool for SGE jobs?

Tags: hpc

I am looking for a tool to specify pipelines of arbitrary multiple jobs with dependencies for the Sun Grid Engine. I can wire things together myself but I am hoping for something more declarative and reusable.

Can anyone recommend such a tool or has anyone adapted an existing build system/dependency manager for compute jobs on SGE?

Answer (score 2):

[Makeflow](http://www3.nd.edu/~ccl/software/makeflow/) describes dependencies using the Make syntax.  It natively supports SGE as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the qmake command that comes with grid engine?  A bit limited as the individual subjobs can't really be parallel but since you mentioned make...

Answer (score 0):

[Starcluster](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/) uses SGE fairly intelligently.  It is part of a suite of tools that make numpy/scipy installs/deploy operations really easy via EC2.

We have moved away from using SGE, as it is in [developmental flux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Grid_Engine) at the moment.